# Can I use Metasploit to demo penetration testong on Zigbee or Smart meter?

Tags: penetration-test

Does Metasploit have functionality to demo penetration testing on Smart Meter or Zigbee?

Comment: Metasploit modules exploits services rather than products. Smart meter is an embedded device while Zigbee is a protocol suite. A lot of embedded devices can be exploited e.g. home routers by exploiting the services running in them such as HTTP, SNMP etc.

Comment: You must be thinking of Killerbee -- https://code.google.com/p/killerbee/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Contact Metasploit for a list of available modules: http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Short answer is Yes, however, like most IoT Devices, you would not be exploiting hardware-specific vulnerabilities, you would likely need to focus on services running on those devices.

For example if a IoT device connects to a remote server to store captured data into a Database, your could easily research current vulnerabilities that apply to that Database Software.

In order to find out what Services are running on a device connected to an IP-Based Network, you would need to simply run a IP/Port/Service scan while connected to the same network. After a scan is successful, then you may use MetaSploit to execute a payload against the Network or Device.

Comment: Also majority of embedded device vulnerabilities include backdoor/service accounts, hard coded passwords for root, unauthenticated access to supposedly restricted and admin areas etc. Don't assume exploitation only means traditional memory corruptions as reverse engineering the firmware will almost always give juicy information.

Comment: Nice point ! Pen testing also includes identifying hard coded passwords and similar kind of issues !